# ow can i populate a combox from database through jstl

Tags: jstl

Can any one assist me am trying to populate a dropdown box with data in my database using jstl but unable to get the solution. below is my code

SELECT MarketPlace from tblmarketplace

```
 <c:forEach var = "row" items = "${carsList1.rows}">

          <c:set var="MarketPlace" value="${row.MarketPlace}"/>



     </c:forEach>
```

Payment Method

```
  <option style="width : 150px;" rows="6"  value="CASH">CASH</option>
   <option style="width : 150px;" rows="6"items="${MarketPlace}">${MarketPlace}</option></select><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<select style="width: 143px" name="MarketPlace">
     <c:forEach var="car" items="${carsList1.rows}">
          <option value="${car.xxxxxx}"/>
                ${car.xxxxxx}
          </option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
```

xxxxx is the name of field to show.

Comment: Tanx alot it worked as instructed...